# How to mock jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object[] {id, name}, new Mapper())

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to populate mocked list from `jdbcTemplate.query()`so that it can increase coverage percent by passing not Empty check.

I have tried

```
   List<ABC> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery,new Object[]{id,name}, new Mapper());
    if(list.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else if(!list.isEmpty){
            for(....)
    }
```

Test class

```
@InjectMocks
DaoImpl dao;
@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Test
public void retrieveResult(){
when(jdbcTemplate.query(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(Object[].class),Mapper.class)).thenReturn(new ArraList<>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either of the following mock declarations will compile and will match the `query` signature.

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(Object[].class), 
    Mockito.any(Mapper.class)
)).thenReturn(list);

when(jdbcTemplate.query(
    Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.any(Object[].class), 
    ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<Mapper>>any())
)).thenReturn(list);
```

Specifically:

- `Mockito.anyString()` matches the `sqlQuery` parameter in your code
- `Mockito.any(Object[].class)` matches the `new Object[]{id,name}` parameter in your code
- `Mockito.any(Mapper.class)` / `ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<Mapper>>any()` match the `new Mapper()` parameter in your code

Comment: Using both of the above solutions did not solve my problem of getting list as not empty. Not sure why this mocking is not showing up in business logic.Also just to highlight this is under a private method which I am calling through whitebox.invokeMethod

Comment: Will need more details, could you update your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is the business logic - public void methodName(List<ABC> abc){ Set<ABC> set = new HashSet<>(); set = retrieveResult(abc); }      private Set<ABC> retrieveResult(XYZ) { List<ABC> abc = new ArrayList<ABC>(); list = jdbcTemplate.query(stringSql, new Object[] {id , name}, new MApper());  if (list.isEmpty()){ return null;} for(.......)

Comment: Still getting list as empty. jdbcTemplate is not getting mocked after using above solution provided by glytching