# How to mock JdbcTemplace with RowMapper

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I have a EmployeeDaoImpl class wish to mock JdbcTemplate and Rowmapper and set the dummy data to ResultSet. Given small snipper code below. Could you help me out on this.

```
public List<EmployeeTask> getDetails(String sql,String countryCode, int departmentNumber, Status status,
        int sectionNumber,int aisle, String zone ){
    if(status!=null) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { countryCode,departmentNumber, Status.OK,sectionNumber,sectionId,zone}, 
                (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
                    EmployeeTask employeeTask = new EmployeeTask();
                    employeeTask.setDepatmentNumber(rs.getInt("dept_number"));
                    employeeTask.setRemartks(rs.getString("remarks"));
                    return employeeTask;
                });
    } else {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[] { countryCode,departmentNumber, Status.OK,sectionNumber,sectionId,zone}, 
                (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
                    EmployeeTask employeeTask = new EmployeeTask();
                    employeeTask.setDepatmentNumber(rs.getInt("dept_number"));
                    employeeTask.setRemartks(rs.getString("remarks"));
                    return employeeTask;
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new Object\[\] {id, name}, new Mapper())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597280/how-to-mock-jdbctemplate-querysqlquery-new-object-id-name-new-mapper)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither your question nor the code snippet explains details about the context in which this Dao is implemented and used.

In general, I would recommend you to read the following article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-testing

It shows some ways how to test code based on a JdbcTemplate.